# Sudden low volume in bluetooth headphones

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I recently bought a pair of bluetooth headphones (Philips SHB7250) which I paired with my laptop (Dell, Lattitude E7450) that runs Windows 7 Enterprise. The first day everything worked fine, but the day after the volume in the headphones was suddenly extremely low. When I increase the volume to max on both my headphones and on the computer I can just barely hear the music / sounds. And I have no clue why this is.

I've tried pairing it with my mobile phone which works just fine, and using the headphones with a jack cable also works just fine - so it must be some settings affecting the bluetooth which are wrong. I just cannot solve the problem.

When I connect my headphones I go to "Devices and Printers", double click the bluetooth icon for my headphones and choose "connect" to "Listen to music".  I then right click on the sound icon at the bottom right corner, choose "Playback devices" and set my bluetooth headphones as default (not the bluetooth headset).

I've tried ticking off "Handfree Telephony" and/or "Headset" under "properties" and "services" without any result.

I am not sure about the settings in the "Volume Control Options" though. Right now I've chosen my headphones as the sound device to show its own volume control and ticked off "All devices currently playing sound". But I've tried all combinations.

All drivers for the headphones are updated and they are fully charged.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone should be interested, I solved the problem with help from a Windows-supporter.

It seems that the problem was caused by a software update (software that had nothing to do with audio) after I connected the headphones the first time. Software and hardware updates may apparently cause such problems.
The issue was solved by going to Device manager -> Sound, video and game controllers -> Bluetooth audio, uninstall the driver (updating it is not sufficient), restart the computer and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

my short term solution-
Task Manager - Service - AudioSrv
Stop the service and restart the service again. 
It will come back to normal volume.
No need to restart window.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing an other audio profile manager such as DFX, Dolby atmos, or MaxxAudio Pro for Dell computers your default sound profile may not be strong enough.